# Will migrations that I make to a django app reflect on the DB that is present in Kubernetes?

Tags: django, kubernetes, mariadb

I have a Django application and I'm using MariaDB as the database. Both of them have been deployed to a namespace on kubernetes. Now I want to add an additional field, so I made changes in the models.py file in the django app. These changes were made locally -  I pulled the code from GIT and just made the changes locally. Normally to apply the changes, I have to run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` and all the changes would've been reflected on to the DB if the DB was present locally.
So now my questions are

1. How can I apply the changes to MariaDb that is there on Kubernetes ?
2. Will running `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` locally and redeploying the django app to kubernetes solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

- If you don't require multiple replicas, then the simplest way to do it would be to run your migrations when the container starts.
- If you require multiple replicas, then you'll have to get creative with jobs and init containers.There's a good article with more info on it here: https://andrewlock.net/deploying-asp-net-core-applications-to-kubernetes-part-7-running-database-migrations/